# ARM Assembly - a simple code

Tags: assembly, arm

I am not really into arm assembly language but I need to figure this code out, I hope somebody can explain it, regards.

```
    .syntax unified
    .align 2
    .global x
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .type x, %function
    x:
    mov r0, sp 
    push {lr}
    bl .L5 
    pop {lr}
    sub r0,r0,r1 
    bx lr .L5: 
    mov r1,sp
    bx lr
    .size x, .-x
```

What result do you expect when you invoke this function?

And lastly, I would like to know what is the purpose of the curly brackets when using the push and pop instructions.

Thanks

Comment: Which in particular of the many, many, easily-available ARM instruction set references and documentation sources are you asking for clarification of?

Comment: code does not make much sense; are there linebreaks missing?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the missing part, this is the full code.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the instructions, with line breaks inserted where they make sense, *literally* mean:

```
mov r0, sp    # put the value of the stack pointer in the register r0
push {lr}     # push the value in the link register on to the stack
bl .L5        # put the value of the next instruction in the link register
              # and then branch to code at label .L5
pop {lr}      # pop the top stack value into the link register
sub r0,r0,r1  # subtract the value in register r1 from the value in register r0
              # and put the difference in register r0
bx lr         # branch to the address in the link register and exchange 
              # instruction set.

.L5:          # Just a label.
mov r1,sp     # put the value of the stack pointer in the register r1
... [assuming more stuff and a return to the caller]
```

So it looks something like: from within your function, call another function.  When that other function returns, update the value of r0 and return it from your function.

Comment: My apologies for the missing part, this is the full code. And lastly, what is the purpose of the brackets {lr}, when using the push and pop instructions. Thank you

Comment: The `{}` denotes a register list (the list of registers to push or pop). In your code the lists only contain a single register (`lr`).

Answer (score 1):

This code works out the amount of stack space required by a Thumb function call that pushes the `lr` register. You can call it from `C` code, e.g.

```
int function_call_stack_requirement = x();
```